# Saving with a foreach loop

Tags: r

I try to use foreach and parallel R loops for the second time and I get some difficulties.

Each iteration of my loop will create a matrix with a a different number of rows.
For example:

```
for (i in 1:66)
{
  #Calculation
  ....


  Mat <- maxtrix(nrow=i, ncol=51863)
  #Calculation
  ...

  save(Mat, file=paste("Mat_",i, sep=""))
}
```

So with my loop I will have 66 different matrix saved.
I need these different 66 files but the code takes a long time so I try to use foreach:

```
Mat <- foreach(i=1:66) %dopar%
{
  #Calculation
  ....


  Mat <- maxtrix(nrow=i, ncol=51863)
  #Calculation
  ...
}

save?
```

And here I don't know what to do because I know I can't save my matrix in my parallel loop but I don't want only one file at the end of the loop. Should I create a list (for foreach) and do another loop to save each element of my list?

Thanks

Comment: `Mat` should already be a list (generated by `foreach`). So you just need to save each element of `Mat` as you suggested yourself. Is this not working for you?

Comment: In fact I don't know how to tell foreach to return a list, is it Mat <- foreach(i=1:66, .combine=list()) ?

Comment: Actually `list` is the default "combine" method, so its not needed. The code you have written in your post should return a list. In other words, when you do `Mat <- foreach(i=1:66) %dopar% ...` then the resulting `Mat` is a list of length 66.

Comment: Ok thanks! I thought I needed to add "combine". In fact it's not the foreach loop which doesn't work but the save!